# How to understand [].copyWithin.call({ length: 5, 3: 1 }, 0, 3)

Tags: javascript

I just began to learn JavaScript, and I have no idea how to understand the following code (from [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/copyWithin#Examples)):

```js
console.log(
  [].copyWithin.call({ length: 5, 3: 1 }, 0, 3)
)
```

Comment: read javascript [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), then read [copyWithin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/copyWithin)

Comment: This may be not exactly the essential knowledge, so you can safely skip this example while you are learning the basics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Array#copyWithin` method can be called with any object with `Function#call`, as long as it has a `length` property and numeric keys. The code on MDN calls the `Array#copyWithin` as the object `{ length: 5, 3: 1 }` as it's `this` or instance value. It is "the array" the method is operating on.

An array is just an object, a special one with `length` and numeric, ordered properties. The same thing is happening here. Instead of an array, they're "mocking" an array by passing an object with `length` and numeric keys.

The same operation happens because both an array and `{ length: 5, 3: 1 }`:

- Have the `length` property
- Have numeric keys

Answer (score 0):

In an oversimplified example, it is similar to:

```js
var object = { length: 5, 3: 1 }

if (object.length > 3)
  object[0] = object[3]
  
console.log(object)

console.log(Array.prototype.copyWithin.call({ length: 5, 3: 1 }, 0, 3))
```

---

In JavaScript, array `[]` is an object `{}` where the positive integer keys are used.
For example, if you enter `[,'a',,]` in the Chrome console, you get something like this:

```
(3) [empty, "a", empty]
  1: "a"
  length: 3
  __proto__: Array(0)
```

If you try `Array.from({ length: 5, 3: 1 })` :

```
(5) [undefined, undefined, undefined, 1, undefined]
  0: undefined
  1: undefined
  2: undefined
  3: 1
  4: undefined
  length: 5
  __proto__: Array(0)
```

The `[].copyWithin.call` is used because the `copyWithin` method is part of `Array.prototype` and can't be called directly on an objects like `{ length: 5, 3: 1 }.copyWithin(0, 3)`.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling to understand it but here is what I understood.

`call` method on functions will accept 3 parameters. first one is an object and then 2 next parameters that are the parameters you need for the function you are calling `call` method on, `copyWithin` array function in this case. let me clarify it more with better English :)

Basically `.call` method for the functions will send an object for the `this` value of that function. for an array that you are calling `copyWithin` method on the array, `this` is basically the array itself which is an object with a length and some other items that it will specify by index and values. The tricky part here is if you pass some empty items, they will still considered in length. So if you pass

```
{length:5, 3:1}
```

instead of `this` for an empty array of `[]` then you would have an array with the length of 5 with items at indexes of 0, 1, and 2 (first three items) to be empty, item at index 3 to be 1 and last item to be empty. which can be like this:

```
[empty,empty,empty,1,empty]
```

on the `call` method for a function, the first parameter is the assigned `this` parameter and the second and third ones are the parameters that you pass to execute the called function as I mentioned at the start.

Now you have an array of 5 items that are all empty except 4th item with index 3 which has the value of 1. After sending the `this` value, you are passing (0,3) as input of the `copyWithin`. You are telling the `call` function to pass 0 and 3 arguments to `copyWithin` array function to copy from the first item of the array with the 4th item to the end which is the last one it means that you are basically telling you have
`[empty,empty,empty,3,empty]`
Replace index 0 with index 3, index 1 with index 4 and you are done since you are at the end of that array. the result would be
`[1,empty,empty,1,empy]`
and if we translate it to `this`, it would be an object, with length of 5, index 0 would be 1 and index 3 would be one too and the rest would be empty which means

```
{0:1, 3:1, length:5}
```

I hope this clarifies it and correct me if I had misunderstandings. Good question